# SerialPort DataReceived event called or maybe sometimes with 7 data bits

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a very strange problem with the DataReceived event not firing under some circumstances in C# VS2010 on windows 8, although the target machine is win 7 or XP.

I am writing an application to replace a very old DOS one that talks to a very old but still current monitoring device that reports using a serial port.
I don't have ready access to the equipment so I have written a simulator for it to run on another PC.
Everything works until I try to use the real equipment.

So the serial settings are

1200 Baud
7 bits
odd parity
1 stop bit
no handshaking

The code is essentially as follows

```
namespace ProjectNamspace
{
    class SerialCom
    {
        static SerialPort ComPort;        

        public SerialCom(SerialCallback callBack, string portName)
        {
            _comPort = new SerialPort();

            _comPort.PortName = portName;
            _comPort.BaudRate = 1200;
            _comPort.Parity = Parity.Odd;
            _comPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            _comPort.DataBits = 7;
            _comPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            //            _comPort.ReadBufferSize = 1;

            _comPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _comPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

            _comPort.NewLine = "\r";
            _comPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            CallBack = new SerialCallback(callBack);
        }
        private void DataReceivedHandler(
                            object sender,
                            SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            byte data;

            while (_comPort.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                data = (byte)_comPort.ReadByte();
                CallBack(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the data comes from another PC my application works perfectly.

If the data comes from the hardware and displayed in teraterm it works perfectly.

If the data comes from the hardware to my application nothing happens.

If I set a breakpoint in the event handler it is never called and yet it works if the data comes from another PC.

I have since tried again and this time my PC was running slow and for some reason it worked except every other character was a question mark 0x3F.

Now the data protocol is very simple. a 7 character packet is repeated continuously until a single acknowledge character is received.
The packets are repeated at a rate of 1 packet every second so there will never be lost traffic so no handshaking is required.

The packet takes the form `12348A<DC4>`
Where `<DC4>` is ascii code 0x14.

I have put an oscilloscope on the serial data line and what I see is what I expect.

My only conclusion at this point is that the .NET serial driver doesn't like 1200 baud or 7 bits maybe.
or maybe it doesn't like the `<DC4>` character.
Does anyone know of problems with the .NET serial driver at these ancient history port settings.

I would like to prove a point by using the old MsComm active x control but cannot find any documentation that isn't .NET so if anyone can point me in the right direction or answer the above I would be grateful

Comment: You say one stop bit and yet your code uses 2. Is this intended?

Comment: _every other character was a question mark_  Could be a ASCII/Unicode issue in the Callback method.

Comment: I agree about the stop bits.  One other thing, it is quite possible that the event handler is being fired for EVERY byte at this data rate.  Accumulate the bytes until you have a packet of the required length.  Without seeing Callback it is hard to know what the issue is.  Normally that is an indication that the bytes being decoded are not part of the encoding.

Comment: dbasnett I am sure the callback is being called once for each character being received, but the point here is that the handler never gets called in the first place so whats in the callback doesn't matter at this point. I will take your sugestion about accumulateing data ready for when it does work. Having said that it works pefectly when the data source is another PC

Comment: dbasnett  Serdalis , Sorry youre right about the stop bitss I was initially told it was two stop bits. Thats not the complete code as the settings get changed later. The equipment turned out to be only using one stop bit. In any case teraterm works regardless of being set to 1 or two bits. I currently have every thing set to 1 stop bit and it still doesn't work

Comment: Hans, I didn't see that one, it doesn't answer the problem but the portmon link could be useful.

Comment: Henk That did cross my mind, but from what I have read using byte as the variable type should fix that unless I have missed something.

Comment: In .NET, `char != byte`. You interchange the 2 quite easily, be careful. It would explain the PC/PC and Device/Terminal working. Post the code if you're not sure.

Comment: byte. It still doesn't explain why the event handler never gets called. I know the .net serialport returns chars even though the hardware works in bytes so I am working in bytes but looks like I've not done it quite right.

Comment: Just fould this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668088/vb-net-serial-port-character-encoding. Which has the ? problem and implies that this is a byte/char problem.

Comment: Just double checked the documentation for the fuction I used 'ReadByte' and it does indead return bytes and ReadChar returns chars. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbyte.aspx). it warns agains mixing the two as the buffers get misaligned. I am not doing both just reading bytes which makes me think there is something wrong that I have no control of.

Comment: There is this warning but I don't understand the implecations of it. NOTE!. Because the SerialPort class buffers data, and the stream contained in the BaseStream property does not, the two might conflict about how many bytes are available to read. The BytesToRead property can indicate that there are bytes to read, but these bytes might not be accessible to the stream contained in the BaseStream property because they have been buffered to the SerialPort class.